# Getting type of a property of a TypeScript class using keyof operator

Tags: typescript

As stated in the documentation of TypeScript about the `keyof` operator, one can get a property of an object instance using the function below.

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, name: K) {
    return o[name];
}
```

Of course, one can get the type of the property by replacing `return o[name]` into `return typeof o[name]`. Is there a way to retrieve the type of the property *without* passing any object instance?

```
function getPropertyType<T>(name: keyof T) {
    // something like T[name]?
}
```

Comment: According to TypeScript's no goals number 5: "Add or rely on run-time type information in programs, or emit different code based on the results of the type" I'm afraid this might not be possible as it sounds like type reflection to me what you are trying to do. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals

Comment: @k0pernikus I don't think this question requires any thing related to runtime information or different code compilation due to types. It's all static typing.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
type PropType<TObj, TProp extends keyof TObj> = TObj[TProp];
```

and get type of an object property by doing:

```
type MyPropType = PropType<ObjType, '<key>'>;
```

which is the same as the way of using `Pick` in typescript, and it can report compile error if there's any invalid `key` passed in.

**Updates**

As @astoilkov suggested, a simpler alternative is `PropType['key']`.

Comment: A simpler solution is `ObjType['key']`. No need for defining an extra type and the syntax is easier to read.

Comment: Thanks, I preferred the shorthand e.g. `private connection: Database['connection'];`.

Comment: @astoilko, your solution has changed my life. 

Comment: I don't see PropType in the typescript spec. Seems like it's just a react concept??

Answer (score 152):

Yes, [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) work just fine:

```
type BarType = FooType['bar'];
```

It expects in this case that `FooType` is an object like:

```
type FooType = {
    bar: string;
}
```

It sets `BarType` to the same type as `FooType['bar']`, so to a `string`.

PS: `FooType` can also be an interface or class.

Comment: Note that if using eslint, you'll want to make sure you're using the "new" `@babel/eslint-parser` library to avoid syntax errors. More details in [this](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/766) github issue.

Comment: If you're having trouble because `FooType` can be null or undefined, use [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype). `type BarType = NonNullable<FooType>['bar']`

Comment: Just a note to create a type which is the union of all the properties `type Properties<T extends Object> = T[keyof T]`

Answer (score 29):

> Of course, one can get the type of the property by replacing `return o[name]` into `return typeof o[name]`.

Not really... if you did that:

```
function getTypeofProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, name: K) {
    return typeof o[name];
}
```

You would get a return value of the type `"string" | "number" | "boolean" | "symbol" | "undefined" | "object" | "function"`, because you're using the [JavaScript `typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) at *runtime*, which returns a string like `"object"`, not the *compile-time* type seen by TypeScript.

TypeScript also uses the keyword `typeof` as the compile-time [type query operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3.8.10).  You can tell the difference by looking at the places where it appears.  The type query `typeof` only appears in places where you are writing a *type*.  For example:

```
const a = { foo: 0 };
const b: Array<typeof a> = [{ foo: 1 }, { foo: 2 }, {foo: 3}]; 
const c: string = typeof a; // "object"
```

In `b`, you can see that `typeof a` appears where you would write a type expression, so it is a TypeScript type query, and `Array<typeof a>` is evaluated as `Array<{foo: number}>`.  On the other hand, in `c`, `typeof a` appears where you would write an value expression, so it is the JavaScript `typeof` operator, and will evaluate to the string `"object"` at runtime.

---

As @k0pernikus mentioned, TypeScript doesn't (and doesn't intend to) allow you to get compile-time type information at runtime.  So there is no `typeof` operator which acts at runtime and returns compile-time information.

---

Of course, if you want type information about a property at compile time, you *can* do that, using what's called [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types).  Let's examine the return value of that `getProperty()` function:

```
function getProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(o: T, name: K) {
    return  o[name];
} // hover over getProperty to see that the return value is of type T[K]
```

That `T[K]` in a type position means "the type of property with a key of type `K` on an object of type `T`".  Since this is a type-level operation, you can do it at compile-time without declaring any values of the type `T` or `K`.  For example,

```
type RegExpFlags = RegExp['flags']; // RegExpFlags is string
const flags: RegExpFlags = 'ig';
```

Here, you are looking up the `"flags"` key of the type of `RegExp` objects and getting back the `string` type, and you can declare a value of type `RegExp['flags']` without having a value of type `RegExp` anywhere.

---

That's the closest I can come to answering your question without more information about what you need.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: hello, thank you for the answer, it seems a bit hard to understand for me; could you please give an example of how to get the type of a class property (for example string) at compile time ? Thank you

Comment: Does the documentation about [lookup types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) (also called "index access types") help?   If you have `class Foo { bar: string = "baz" }` and then `type FooBar = Foo["bar"]`, the type `FooBar` will be `string`.

Comment: that documentation for lookup types was pretty abstract, what really is "type Foobar" ? what i needed was a string describing the type, like "String" or "Number"; in the end what worked was http://blog.wolksoftware.com/decorators-metadata-reflection-in-typescript-from-novice-to-expert-part-4

Comment: You know what, thinking in terms of a "type-level" operation as you put it, has really cleared up a few things in my head. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to get the type of a property of an object. Some of them are already mentioned and I would like to extend this a bit more.

As a side note, if you use `Conditional Types` in this task, you can avoid type errors. But that depends on the requrement.

**1. `Conditinal Types` with `infer`**

For example, consider the following object

```
const student = {
    name: 'John Doe',
    age: 22,
    dormitory: true
}
```

The task is to get the type of `age` (for example)

```
type AgeTypeUsingInfer<T> = T extends {age: infer K} ? K : never;
type AgeType = AgeTypeUsingInfer<typeof student>
```

`AgeType` will correctly resolve to `number` type.

If you pass any type which does not contain the `age` property, then the returned type will be `never`.

```
const musician = {
    art: 'Pop',
    city: 'Gotham'
}

type MusicianAgeType = AgeTypeUsingInfer<typeof musician>
```

In this case, the type of `MusicianAgeType` will be resolved to `never` without type errors.

**2. `Conditional Types` with `Indexed Access`**

```
type AgeTypeUsingConditionalTypesAndIndexedAccess<T> = T extends {age: any} ? T['age'] : never;

type AgeType2 = AgeTypeUsingConditionalTypesAndIndexedAccess<typeof student>; // number
type MusicianAgeType2 = AgeTypeUsingConditionalTypesAndIndexedAccess<typeof musician>; // never
```

**3. With `Indexed Access`**

```
type AgeTypeUsingIndexedAccess<T extends {age: any}> = T['age'];

type AgeType3 = AgeTypeUsingIndexedAccess<typeof student>; // number
type MusicianAgeType3 = AgeTypeUsingIndexedAccess<typeof musician>; // type error
```

Depending on the requirement, you can assign the type to `never` or let the type error to be surfaced immediately in case if you have passed an object which does not contain the expected property.

Hope this answer is helpful... happy coding :)