# Typescript pick from function argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In TypeScript is there a way for useContext within the following to pick and return the value type from from Provider?

```
function Provider<Props = {value: number}>(props: Props) { }
function useContext<Value>(context: Context<Value>): Pick<Value, 'value'> { return 0 }
```

Such that "Consumer" will return the type: number when used as follows

```
function Consumer<Props>(props: Props) { return useContext(Provider) }
```

...For additional context:

```
interface Component<Props = {}> { (props: Properties<Props>): Node }
interface Context<Value> extends Component<{value: Value}> {}
```

Or alternatively, given

```
function Provider({value, children}: {value: string, children: any}) {
  return h(Context, {value: 'value'}, children)
}

const value = useContext(Provider)
```

How would one attribute the constant "value" to the "value" found in the object {value: 'value'} assuming that the function "h" returns an interface:

```
interface {type: Context, props: {value: 'value}, children: children}
```

I've tried to Pick, props> where Type is "Provider" then Pick from the result of that Pick, props>, 'value'>.

That however didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a nifty way to extract property types called '[lookup types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894524/getting-type-of-a-property-of-a-typescript-class-using-keyof-operator)' ([TypeScript 2.1 Notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html)).
The syntax is:

```js
MyType['value'] // number
```

Where `MyType` contains a property `value: number`.

---

Edit: I'm having trouble following your example, I tried expanding `useContext's` `'context'` parameter and ended up with this:

```js
   function useContext<Value>(context: Context<Value>): Pick<Value, 'value'>;
=> function useContext<Value>(context: Component<{value: Value}>): Pick<Value, 'value'>
=> function useContext<Value>(context: (props: Properties<{value: Value}>) => Node): Pick<Value, 'value'>
```

If we follow the `Value` type to the 3rd expansion we see that there is no constraint; nothing telling the compiler that the `Value` type must have a `'value'` property. The only way for the Typescript compiler to return a type from `useContext(...)` based on `Value["value"]` is if there's some constraint telling the compiler that `'value'` exists on the type.

One option, if you add a type constraint `<Props extends {value: number} = {value: number}>` to `Component` and `Provider` the compiler will be able infer that the `props` has a `'value'` property.

Another option, explicitly tell the compiler which property you already know to exist using `keyof` and passing in the key literal string (added 'key' parameter, and changed return type to `Pick<Value, K>`):

```js
function useContext<Value, K extends keyof Value>(context: Context<Value>, key: K): Pick<Value, K> {
  // ...
}

var value = useContext(Provider, 'value');
```

Comment: I've updated the question with more context. Yes lookup types as i understand them won't work in this case, at least as far as i've tried.

Comment: Thanks, lookup types is what i needed, i was under the wrong impression about what `Pick` does in typescript.