# Extend and spread functions from another class

Tags: javascript, typescript

Below I have class `E` which extends `W`. Both have a property meow, which is an object of functions. I'd like to take the functions from `W` and spread them over `E`'s. However I would also like to access the original functions on W from within the classes on E. I assumed that I could do this through calling super directly but it's not working.

```
class W { 
    meow = {
        woof: () => {
            '2'
        }
    }
}

class E extends W { 
    meow = {
        ...super.meow,
        hello: () => {
            return super.meow.woof()
        }
    }
}

const x = new E()

console.log(x.meow.hello())
```

Is there any way this syntax could work?

---

Real world example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Reads {
    one() {
        return '2'
    }

    byId() {
        return '2'
    }
}

class ReadsProp {
    read = new Reads()
}

class UserReads extends Reads {
    byEmail() {
        return this.one()
    }
}

class UserReadsProp extends ReadsProp {
    read = new UserReads()
}

class UserRepo { 
    read = new UserReadsProp().read
}

const userRepo = new UserRepo()

console.log(userRepo.read.byEmail())
```

Answer (score 2):

### Intro

I wouldn't do it that way (though I think I've found a way to force it to work). After the version forcing it to work, I've shown how I think I'd do it instead.

*(You seem to prefer to rely on ASI avoid writing semicolons, so I've done that below.)*

### Why it isn't working

The reason what you have isn't working is that `E`'s `meow` *replaces* `W`'s `meow`. Properties are created with "define" semantics, and so when `E`'s properties are created, `W`'s `meow` is thrown away (before the initializer is evaluated) and `E`'s `meow` is created in its place on the object being created. `super.meow` is the same as `this.meow` in the initializer, and has the value `undefined`. Spreading `undefined` is a no-op.

### Getting it to work

Here's the fairly ugly way I've forced it to work:

```
type PropType<TObj, TProp extends keyof TObj> = TObj[TProp]

class W {
    meow = {
        woof: () => '2'
    }
}

class E extends W {
    // @ts-ignore 2564 (not definitely assigned in ctor -- it is, in the super)
    meow: PropType<W, "meow"> & {
        hello: () => string
    }
    constructor() {
        super()
        // @ts-ignore 2565 (not assigned -- it is, in the super)
        this.meow.hello = () => {
            return this.meow.woof()
        }
    }
}

const x = new E()

console.log(x.meow.hello())
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAFXBAPMg8gIwFYA0Uy8SUEAHsBAHYAmAzlANYQgIBmxueAfFAF5u+ANolEYALoAoaQGMANgEMGTAOpQA3tKi6oAWwgIA7oK069l4wk4AuKAAoAlIP4ByAExuLugL7T-eWVVKABRcipaRigNbUsAenioAAFgBgBaAEsAcxoEOGgPAFYANgAWRzzgKDoIDkyaTOoFECgVBhyaCDooBqg5YHyodPTe6syGIj7gAAtoBgBXSDgnHwMjY3tSFDR0NSIAIkMTA-4AMnNLSzmFBQR7Z1coBmA4Buy1-0s5BBoXuAWA3yjziV10i2WzjWCSSqQynXyhVKRUqCGq7U63WGoyavUmvRoUFm8yWEBW0L0swmADpjsZqTc7mZHgJ+KCwZYCsAFnBCVSGLSNtTrJwoRyoF89P5Aj8-tUKGYuqZQlD5L8GAgFBBqXdsg4KIKTAyILcEM4nEA)

As you can see, it involves suppressing a couple of TypeScript errors. Here's what that does:

- I've declared `meow` for TypeScript only:
      meow: PropType & {
          hello: () => string
      }
- Doing that requires extracting the type of `W`'s `meow` (so `E`'s has `woof`), which I did by using `PropType` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432326/157247):

  ```
  type PropType<TObj, TProp extends keyof TObj> = TObj[TProp]
  ```
- Then, since we know that `W` creates `meow`, I've extended the one `W` creates in `E`'s constructor:

  ```
  this.meow.hello = () => {
      return this.meow.woof()
  }
  ```

  If you had multiple functions to add, you could assign them via `Object.assign`.
- I also updated `woof` so it actually returns the `'2'`, so we could see that `hello` successfully calls it.

### What I'd do instead

I'd create classes for `meow`:

```
class WMeow {
    woof() {
        return '2'
    }
}

class W {
    meow = new WMeow()
}

class EMeow extends WMeow {
    hello() {
        return this.woof()
    }
}

class E extends W {
    meow = new EMeow()
}

const x = new E()

console.log(x.meow.hello())
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=23&pc=28#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqCyBTA9gd2gbwFDV9VyyAZgBQCUmOe1ATogC4CuNAdtAOQBM7VuAvlgFZQkGLErUAtinQBeaC0ToEM8oKzDwUaAFEkaaIgAe9RCwAmY-emzUAFohAhk5CdTx0mraPTsBLCAA6AmI1agEhEW0dQxMzSzg3XGkDeUV0PVUydWFkFgh6aCNoNKVdNVz85BBEQOcAcxIjQJTUQIcnFzIyIA)

Now, that doesn't give `meow`'s methods access to the `W` or `E` instance. The fact you were using arrow function ssuggests to me that you wanted them to have access to `this` (the `W` or `E` instance).

If you wanted that access, `WMeow` and `EMeow` could both accept a parent instance:

```
class WMeow<T extends W> {
    constructor(protected parent: T) {
    }
    woof() {
        this.parent.wmethod()
        return '2'
    }
}

class W {
    meow = new WMeow<W>(this)

    wmethod() {
        console.log("wmethod")
    }
}

class EMeow<T extends E> extends WMeow<T> {
    hello() {
        this.parent.emethod()
        return this.woof()
    }
}

class E extends W {
    meow = new EMeow(this)

    emethod() {
        console.log("emethod")
    }
}

const x = new E()

console.log(x.meow.hello())
```

[On the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=35&pc=28#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqCyBTA9gdwDwBVqIB4BdEA7AExlgD5oBvAKGgemGSInwCcBXYfZdgCgAO7ZIR6IS0QWHbF8ALmiYAlDXqMAvuoapkyAGb9VdRqej4AFgEsIAOmmyi+W6gC2iS8hJHtZ2fk52ImgAcgAmEN8tLVpQSHI1U3c0aABeaCJEVDgkNHRKfksbZVpfNw8LLyNEswZmVmQQRFsQZABzfgAics8STpLTaNK4qGgAUVyMbDxCUhgxqhniMhyUKaoTRgtEEFbqzdqiuwc5W0R3XqMAbl9Tf0Dgo5c9QwHNWhiR+ZwCZYSD6DJbLpTLZCZrQrWCAlXznCpVYy3Rj1CCNZqtDqdOG9fpRD7DFhsaC4NIZLLjHyxQlolrtfi4WxA2zbXbIIzKIA)

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you ask about "functions", but `meow` is a member variable. `super` is about calling functions.

[JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

> The super keyword is used to access and call functions on an object's parent.

[TS](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#4.9)

> Super property accesses are used to access base class member functions from derived classes and are permitted in contexts where `this` (section 4.2) references a derived class instance or a derived class constructor function.

So it's not like [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) for example.

A thing what you can do is making it a function, like a getter. That would work for the one level of inheritance shown in the question:

```js
class W { 
    _meow = {
        woof: () => {
            return '2'
        }
    }
    get meow() { return this._meow; }
}

class E extends W {
    meow = {
        ...super.meow,
        hello: () => {
            return super.meow.woof()
        }
    }
}

const x = new E()

console.log(x.meow.hello())
console.log(x.meow.woof())
```

Added the second `log` to show that the spread syntax is operational here (if you comment the `...super.meow`, `x.meow.woof()` will die).
Side note: `() => {'2'}` is wrong. It either has to be `() => '2'`, or `() => {return '2'}`.
Side note2: it works as a snippet, because it (and the question too) is JavaScript, not TypeScript. `meow` is a completely ad-hoc object. TypeScript is what T.J. Crowder shows, and it involves a lot more typing.

---

Apparently TS compiler produces code which in JS would be needed for supporting an inheritance chain only (moving the "extension code" into a constructor), that means a setter is required too for `meow`. This code uses [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to extend the already existing `meow`, and works both in JS and TS:

```js
class W { 
    _meow = {
        woof: () => {
            return '2'
        }
    }
    get meow() { return this._meow; }
    set meow(m) { Object.assign(this._meow, m); }
}

class E extends W {
    meow = {
        ...super.meow,
        hello: () => {
            return super.meow.woof()
        }
    }
}

const x = new E()

console.log(x.meow.hello())
console.log(x.meow.woof())
```

Fun fact: as this variant extends the already existing `meow` "property", it does not actually depend on the `...super.meow` part, but without it TS starts complaining that the `hello`-only object is not assignable to the (implicit) type of `meow` in `W`,

> ```
> Property 'woof' is missing in type '{ hello: () => string; }' but required in
>    type '{ woof: () => string; }'.
> ```

The compiled code works nevertheless, as JS actually does not care.

Comment: Although your code snippet works in JS (**if** the env has class fields support), it [doesn't work in TS](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?target=7#code/MYGwhgzhAEDq0G9oChpugfQLYFMD2A7tALyKroUF54BmAXNABQCUJAfGRV+gE44AuAVx4A7aAHIATOPLcAvrOgKKAcwHRchFomh8ho6PwAWASwgA6bPgIBuJcgXJQkGAFFoOAB78cIgCYw8AiKmkSkwdxo5tEQggAOODzmoQA0ihRGOCAgeAzaxBwRkRR6wmKxCUmh5lS0LOnoyo0OyE54IhD80J4k0CI4RK71bR14IDjmOSqMnsnW5pnZeCzMIxBjE1Mzc4Q11DQrQA) compiled to JS (not even targeting ES2020 or ESNext). (Look in the console for the error.) It might when TypeScript switches to outputting class fields, but...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, I added some fix. Otherwise I tried to make minimal changes only, that is why class fields are left there for the JS code.