# how to implement a type-safe generic setter

Tags: typescript

**Playground is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgezAFXBAPMg8gIwFYA0Uy8SUEAHsBAHYAmAzlANYQgIBmxueAfFAF5u%20ANolEYALoBuKACg5oSFACCgqAG8AhgEYAXFAbA4ASxoBzIloBMBmgFcAtjghwAvgoA2EYFC0G1IW19KAByDgQEUKtbKAAWazdpBQ57GgBjYBMEGkMfUkg4UCwaFQAKMAlXUANWdi4VOSIANwMC1Eh0FSIlCE4oSqRqkF4ASgNmhBM6TQUoefmtEUHC0El1ZtkAei2oAHcACxAoEyZgA9OoDi0TTzNzAH45BfkPOQZ8qqKQEvLQ3Wi8Wso1kCx2UHOlwYBwQ9k8M2utwhCAhaAAtOkDhB0sx3p8ht9fmV-tZAaE4gBmUIg%20bgugmYDABBzBSs1kvBRAA)**

I am trying to define a generic type-safe setter function in Typescript.
Something like the following:

```
 type A = {a1: string, a2: number}
 let a: A = {a1: 'foo', a2: 42};
 setPropertyOnA('a1', 42);    // this should fail to type-check
 setPropertyOnA('a2', '43');  // ditto
```

Below is what I have done (playground link is given above):

```
type PropType<TObj, TProp extends keyof TObj> = TObj[TProp]; 

type A = {a1: string, a2: number}

let a: A = {a1: 'foo', a2: 42};

function setPropertyOnA(property: keyof A
                      , v: PropType<A, typeof property>): void {

    a[property] = v; // Q1. why is this failing?
}

setPropertyOnA('a1', 42);    // Q2. this should fail to type-check
setPropertyOnA('a2', '43');  // ditto
```

The `PropType` utility was copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432326/274677)

On the line marked with `Q1` I get:

> Type 'PropType<A, "a1" | "a2">' is not assignable to type 'never'.
> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)

On the two lines marked with `Q2` I was expecting Typescript to complain, yet it doesn't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you should lock a specific key with generic. Also you can simplify your code without using `PropType`:

```
function setPropertyOnA<T extends keyof A>(property: T, v: A[T]): void {
     a[property] = v; // now it works
}

setPropertyOnA('a1', 42);    // it's failed
setPropertyOnA('a2', '43');  // it's failed
```

Moreover, you can write a function to set property not only to a specific type of object:

```
function setProperty<T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, property: K, v: T[K]): void {
     obj[property] = v;
}
```