# How to access the type of a function defined inside an interface?

Tags: typescript

I have an interface which is declared like this

```
interface SomeInterface {
  (someArg: string): string;
  someProp: string;
}
```

If I want to access the type of `someProp`, I know I can do

```
const value: SomeInterface['someProp'] = 'asd';
```

What I don't know is the way of accessing the type of the function

```
const func: SomeInterface['???'] = (_str) => str;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting type of a property of a typescript class using keyof operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894524/getting-type-of-a-property-of-a-typescript-class-using-keyof-operator)

Comment: I need the type of the function inside the interface, not of a property

Comment: A function inside a class **is** a property. The type of a function is a function? Which type are you referring to exactly?

Comment: @UzielLudueña SomeInterface **is** a function, so you can just do `const func: SomeInterface = (_str) => _str`, assuming you also fill in the someProp value on a later line. Or are you trying to remove someProp from the type?

Comment: I guess to get the pure function type one could use `(...args: Parameters<SomeInterface>) => ReturnType<SomeInterface>`

Comment: @NicholasTower thanks. I didn't notice that if I define `someProp` later, TS does not throw an error.

Comment: Could you assign a name to the function?