# TypeScript how associate enam with union types and get returned object property type?

Tags: typescript, types, enums, typescript-generics, generic-function

I have an enum and its associated union type:

```
type User = { name: string, age: number }

export enum StorageTypeNames {
    User = "user",
    Users = "referenceInfo",
    IsVisibleSearchPanel = "searchPanel",
    PropertyPanelInfo = 'propertyPanelInfo'
};

type StorageType =
    | { name: StorageTypeNames.User, data: User }
    | { name: StorageTypeNames.Users, data?: User[] }
    | { name: StorageTypeNames.IsVisibleSearchPanel, data?: boolean }
    | { name: StorageTypeNames.PropertyPanelInfo, data: {visibility: boolean};
```

and there is a class using these types in the method of which I am trying to implement a generic function

```
export class StorageHelper {
    private static readonly _storage = window.localStorage;

    static get<T>(type: StorageType): T;
    static get<T>(type: StorageTypeNames): Pick<StorageType, 'data'>;
    static get<T>(type: StorageType | StorageTypeNames): T {
        let data: string | null = null;
        if(typeof type === 'string')
            data = this._storage.getItem(type);
        else
            data = this._storage.getItem(type.name);
        return data ? JSON.parse(data) : null;
    }
}
```

as a result I want to get this:
depending on the incoming argument, the typescript suggested the properties of the outgoing object:

```
const userData = StorageHelper.get(StorageTypeNames.User).data. //typeScript dosent help
```

[image]

please tell me how to do it, thanks in advance

Comment: Don't have a final solution, but you don't have help from the intellisense because Typescript doesn't know which specific type is data on line 27. 
So you try to parse a string coming from storage and the Pick will get the data property, but data can be of type User, User[], boolean or a literal object.

Comment: yes i understand it, but i'm trying to figure out how to bind the input argument and the union type I have presented
so that typescript understands which of data type

Comment: As a workaround, you can cast the type you need:
const userData = StorageHelper.get(StorageTypeNames.User).data as User;

I know this is a bad solution but at least keeps you from being stuck until you get the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call signatures of `get()` don't express what you're doing.  It looks like you want to accept a parameter *either* of some subtype of `StorageType`, in which case you return a value of the same subtype; *or* of some subtype of `StorageTypeNames`, in which case you return a value of the corresponding member of `StorageType`.

For the first case, you need `get()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `T` of `type`, where `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `StorageType`.  And then the return type is also `T`:

```
static get<T extends StorageType>(type: T): T;
```

Your mistake was by making `type` of type `StorageType` instead of type `T` constrained to `StorageType`, since then the compiler has no idea what `T` is.

For the second case, you want `get()` to be generic in the type `K` of `type`, where `K` is now constrained to `StorageTypeNames`.  But now you want to take the `StorageType` [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) and filter it to get just the one member whose `name` property is of type `K`.  We can use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to filter unions this way.  Here's the call signature:

```
static get<K extends StorageTypeNames>(type: K): Extract<StorageType, { name: K }>;
```

And then you can implement the method however you want:

```
static get(type: StorageType | StorageTypeNames) {
  /* impl */
}
```

(although if your method actually has a chance of returning `null` you should make the output type include [the `null` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined) like `T | null` or `Extract<StorageType, {name: K}> | null` so that someone using the widely-recommended [`--strictNullChecks` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#strictnullchecks-on) would benefit from the extra checking.)

Let's test it out:

```
StorageHelper.get(StorageTypeNames.User).data.age.toFixed(2); // okay
StorageHelper.get(
  StorageHelper.get(StorageTypeNames.PropertyPanelInfo)
).data.visibility // okay
```

Looks good.  The compiler understands that, for example, `get(StorageTypeNames.User)` returns a value of type `{ name: StorageTypeNames.User, data: User }`, which is what you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-dZAOJECIGAMCIAgpM1iBaCEIcYBmEQfkkLeKAACk5AAeQ0NYwFiBB4y-RdiCPQcThOfh20VcJygw4B43bZZK0eIwUzWL81mUNZFAAMXIIQIG2eMACZoKgAB6bSoFEABrHAQF4oD+MEsdrD4pUkCEkSgLEiEKWaSoaXaN8+CkmSWRhdlOTNXT9KMky+CAA)

Comment: I'd accept this as the correct answer. Looks interesting and easy to read and understand. Generics is still something that sometimes I can't get my head around. Makes my brain hurt ahah. Glad I learned something today. Thanks!

Comment: I agree! it's very cool! I'm glad to learn new things, and the second option is absolutely what I needed

Comment: a little note on the answer, as a result I should have received this:

`static getData<K extends StorageTypeNames>(type: K): Extract<StorageType, { name: K }>['data'];`
because the method was supposed to return not the entire object, but its `data` property type

referring to [Getting type of a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894524/getting-type-of-a-property-of-a-typescript-class-using-keyof-operator)

Comment: That makes sense and what I originally thought, but your own example usage shows `StorageHelper.get(StorageTypeNames.User).data.` implying that the output has a `data` property and is presumably the entire object.