# List properties and types of a class

Tags: node.js, typescript, reflection, annotations

Is there a way in TypeScript, maybe a post-processor, transformer, reflection API or annotation system to get the properties of a class and the types of the property, like Python's `__annotations__`?

This is what I want in code:

```js
class A {
   public k: string;
   public o: number;
   public s: AnotherClass;
}

sometool(A); // And get something like:

{
  k: String,
  o: Number,
  s: AnotherClass
}
```

Comment: You might be able to cobble something together using the answers to [Getting type of a property of a typescript class using keyof operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45894524/215552), but it seems like you're looking to gain runtime-access to compile-time information...

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a broader context, what you need that for. You could possibly be falling into the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Wiktor Zychia Nope, is not, I'm trying to export the native typescript class as model to a OpenAPI spec model in a easy way (like python FastAPI), I think this could be possible with Typescript as a superset language, that's why I'm asking

Comment: This context sounds ok, you could have put that into the question in the first place. If I were in your shoes I'd start with inspecting existing tools like typeconv